Populate the add new custom field dropdown in wordpress add new product
A plugin (Product Feed PRO for WooCommerce) has hijacked the add new custom field dropdown in add new product.  Deactivating the plugin doesnt repopulate the list to what it was.
It seems quite simple but cant find the code.  How do I take back control of the add new custom field dropdown menu from functions.php and put my field names in the list?

Code for anyone else looking:
function set_default_meta($post_ID){
add_post_meta($post_ID,'Custom Field name ','Custom field Value',true);   
add_post_meta($post_ID,'2nd field name','2nd value',true);   
return $post_ID;
}
add_action('wp_insert_post','set_default_meta');

